# Missing icons on Salesforce report buttons in Chrome

Tags: lightning-experience, reporting, svg-icon, icon

The icons in Salesforce report buttons are missing in Chrome, since several months now.

This somewhat related known issue [Some icons disappear in Chrome 84](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001SqocQAC) is "In review" and even though the related [chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1107442) is supposed "Fixed/Closed", the issue persists on newer Chrome version.

**Chrome version 91.0.4472.101 (Windows 10 / 64-bit)**

[image]

Found quite a lot of errors in Chrome console when viewing the report, just posting a sample extract here:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
throws at webpack:///./src/core/common/di/message/content/content-message.sender.ts?:16:30 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
    at eval (webpack:///./src/core/common/di/message/content/content-message.sender.ts?:16)
No label found for section "EclairNgChartSections" and name "axisBarLength".
value @ lightningReport.source.2c86738476e81aae58bc.js:1
lightningReport.source.2c86738476e81aae58bc.js:1 
No label found for section "EclairNgChartSections" and name "axisBars".
value @ lightningReport.source.2c86738476e81aae58bc.js:1
lightningReport.source.2c86738476e81aae58bc.js:1 
No label found for section "EclairNgChartSections" and name "trellis".
value @ lightningReport.source.2c86738476e81aae58bc.js:1

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
throws at webpack:///./src/core/common/di/message/content/content-message.sender.ts?:16:30 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
    at eval (webpack:///./src/core/common/di/message/content/content-message.sender.ts?:16)
```

Anyone having same issue on Chrome ? Any workaround ?

**Works fine when viewing report in Firefox - version 89.0 (64-bit)**

[image]

Comment: Have the same version `Version 91.0.4472.101 (Official Build) (64-bit), WIndows 10` but all seems fine. Is it happening will all the orgs that you login with this browser? On classic some images are blocked due to Third party cookies, maybe  you can enable them for a while for testing only.

Comment: Tried several orgs, same issue in developer org, production and sandbox. This happens on any salesforce report in lightning experience but thanks will check if third party cookies are blocked

Comment: Try with unchecking  "Disable cache" in Chrome -> DevTools -> Network

Comment: "Disable cache" is already unchecked
no difference, when enabling third party cookies

Comment: @vinay any other pointers how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you try on other machine with chrome 91 version also can you give a try by enabling 'Disable cache' and check(this might not work).  Will update if I find any other checkpoints.